# Prevent users from sharing network printers in Server 2008R2 Win 7 environment

Tags: permissions, group-policy, network-printer

I have a server 2008R2-level AD domain in which all the printers are networked. I have a highly mobile workforce of about 350 in the facility, and when they move from one work area to another, they typically map to the network printer in their current work area.

Unfortunately, when installing the networked printer, the option to "Share this printer" comes up during the install. When they share the networked printer (despite being told not to), it replicates the printer on the Print server, and it cannot be removed until I go into the specific computer CN and delete it from there. This has led to spooling issues on the print server, as you might imagine.

Is there any way to prevent users from sharing their installed printers without interfering with thier ability to use shared files and network printers? I can see in group policy that I can disable file and print sharing altogether, but I don't want to remove access to domain shared resources.

Comment: `When they share the networked printer (despite being told not to), it replicates the printer on the Print server, and it cannot be removed until I go into the specific computer CN and delete it from there` - I don't understand this statement. How is the printer being "replicated" to the print server? How is the printer being published to AD? AFAIK, publishing the shared printer to AD isn't an option during the Add Printer Wizard, you have to manually do that after the printer is added from the Sharing tab of the printer properties.

Comment: Is it possible to install all the printers via GP in order to prevent users to install them by themselves? Moving from one area then means just changing the default printer. Personally I prefer _pull printing_ which allows only one universal driver and all the documents then needs to be released when at the printer. It's better for both security and ecological reasons.

Comment: They are connecting to printers published to AD. When they "reshare" the printers, it replicates a shared printer on the print server, but it does not publish it in the directory - however, I end up with 5-10 redirected printers on the print server. Actually, if I've got something configured wrong, perhaps that is the problem.

Comment: Esa - I would potentially like to be able to do that, but I have no budget for replacing printers, some of which are the old (and dependable) HP 9050s - I'm not sure if I could configure pull printing for them. Or perhaps I simply don;t know how I would configure that.

Comment: joeqwerty - I just talked to one of the perpetrators, and had him walk me through what he was doing. What I think is happening is that they are installing with IP addresses rather than using the AD lookup. After installing with the IP, Windows allows them to share the printer. This shared printer is then (for some reason) being listed on the print server as a redirected shared printer. Perhaps what I actually need to do is prevent installation of non-AD published printers?

Comment: I've never seen that before. Are these users logging onto the printer server with Remote Desktop Services by any chance?

Comment: By default, accessing a print server via Remote Desktop creates redirected printers.

Comment: That's an interesting lead - They shouldn't be able to RDP into the server, but I'll check to make sure one of the other admins didn't inadvertently change a permission somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the point and print restrictions policy:

Point and Print Restrictions: This policy setting controls the client Point and Print behavior, including the security prompts for Windows Vista computers. The policy setting applies only to non-Print Administrator clients, and only to computers that are members of a domain.

When the policy setting is enabled, the following conditions obtain: •Windows XP and later clients will only download print driver components from a list of explicitly named servers. If a compatible print driver is available on the client, a printer connection will be made. If a compatible print driver is not available on the client, no connection will be made. 
•You can configure Windows Vista clients so that security warnings and elevated command prompts do not appear when users Point and Print, or when printer connection drivers need to be updated.

When the policy setting is not configured, the following conditions obtain: •Windows Vista client computers can point and print to any server. 
•Windows Vista computers will show a warning and an elevated command prompt when users create a printer connection to any server using Point and Print. 
•Windows Vista computers will show a warning and an elevated command prompt when an existing printer connection driver needs to be updated. 
•Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP client computers can create a printer connection to any server in their forest using Point and Print.

When the policy setting is disabled, the following conditions obtain: •Windows Vista client computers can create a printer connection to any server by using Point and Print. 
•Windows Vista computers will not show a warning or an elevated command prompt when users create a printer connection to any server by using Point and Print. 
•Windows Vista computers will not show a warning or an elevated command prompt when an existing printer connection driver has to be updated. 
•Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP client computers can create a printer connection to any server by using Point and Print. 
•The Users can only point and print to computers in their forest setting applies only to Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP SP1 (and later service packs).

Comment: I'm implementing this now, and I'll see how it works - with luck, no more "Redirected" printers will show up on the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is old and answered, but I noticed in one of your comments that you want to get rid of "Redirected" printers.

Redirection is a feature of RDP that is separate from whether the user has shared a printer from their desktop, and has separate GPO settings.

```
User Settings
> Administrative Templates
>> Windows Components
>>> Remote Desktop Services
>>>> Remote Desktop Session Host
>>>>> Printer Redirection
>>>>>> Do not allow client printer redirection
```

The purpose of redirection is to allow you to print to your normal printers from remote systems.